# Resetting button to original text pyqt5

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

I have a button called "start" and when I click the button, it becomes "Pause", when I click it again, it doesn't revert back to "start" it just stays as is and I need to be able to have it go back to the original text. How do I go about this? Right now I have this

```
    def button_click(self):
        self.start_button.setText("Pause")
```

This changes the start button to pause but I don't know how to go from pause to start.

Comment: «when I click it again, it doesn't revert back to "start"» what makes you think it should? You probably connected the `clicked` signal to your `button_click` function, so you're practically saying "when I click the button, change its text to Pause". Objects don't *magically* remember their previous state on their own and restore it when you want them to, you have to provide that logic.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set a property on an object, it doesn't "remember" its previous state, unless *you* provide that feature in some way.

A simple solution, at least for boolean-like objects, would be to store the current state, and toggle between them.

```
        self.start_button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.start_state = False

    # ...

    def button_click(self):
        self.start_state = not self.start_state
        if self.start_state:
            self.start_button.setText("Pause")
        else:
            self.start_button.setText("Start")
```

An alternative could be to use a *checkable* button instead, which is also more clear from the UX perspective as the pressed/unpressed state is much more visible to the eye than a string (imagine using "Start"/"Stop", which are very similar).

Since the [`clicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) also sends the checked state automatically, you can add the argument to the function you already have and check that instead.

```
        self.start_button = QPushButton('Start')
        self.start_button.setCheckable(True)

    # ...

    def button_click(self, state):
        if state:
            self.start_button.setText("Pause")
        else:
            self.start_button.setText("Start")
```

Note that for this it's usually preferred to use the [`toggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled) signal instead, since it also reacts to `setChecked()` and `toggle()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a nice fancy way to do this. Probably just do the following:

```py
def button_click(self):
    if self.start_button.text() == "Pause":
        self.start_button.setText("start")
    elif self.start_button.text() == "start":
        self.start_button.setText("Pause")
```

Comment: Note that this won't probably work in many cases: some Qt styles automatically create *mnemonics* for buttons. The result is that when a button text is changed to "Pause", its `text()` can become "&Pause" (the "&" is used for the mnemonic keyboard shortcut, which is shown as an underscored "P"), so the above will never work since the `if ... == "Pause":` will never match. Relying on displayed text (especially for ui elements) for comparisons is usually not a good idea, as there's also a possible localization issue: if a button has localized text, you cannot check it.

Comment: Great points @musicamante! You've piqued my interest, do you have a recommended alternative?

Comment: A state should always be checked against unique possibilities; for buttons it's generally a boolean value, which can be easily set/toggled/checked programmatically without any uncertainty. See my answer for possible implementations. Note that string comparison is not *wrong* per se, it only depends on the context. UI elements always separate what they "show" from what they "do" (or "are"), similarly to what the MVC pattern does: the appearance should reflect the behavior, not the opposite; by comparing the button text you're trying to decide the behavior based on the appearance.

Comment: Obviously there are cases for which string comparison is fundamental, but they are mostly based on some level of restraints: for instance, user input (a text field), but then we're talking about unreliable input (for that we have things like regexes). Then you can have string based restrictions (keys of json formatted data, or attribute names of an object), but in this case we have more control on a possibly structured data model.

Comment: Just to clarify: the mnemonic is "guessed" based on *all* the current mnemonic-able widgets on the current window. This means that if you already have a button with a taken "P" mnemonic, Qt will check agains all available "a" letters, and so on. If all letters are already taken, then it could fall back to the "less" used letter (that depends, mnemonic setting changes if there are special widgets like toolbars or QDialogButtonBoxes or no-modifier shortcuts). That's to say that you cannot even try to use `if 'Pause' in self.start_button.text():`, as you can also have things like `Pau&se`.

Comment: @musicamante Localisation is entirely in the control of the programmer, so it's non-issue here (i.e. just [use `tr()` wherever necessary](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#using-tr-for-all-literal-text)). If a style modifies the text in a way that is outside the programmer's control, most people would consider that a bug. KDE was forced to alter their implementation of this nasty little "feature" after numerous complaints from Qt developers (see [Bug 337491](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337491)).

Comment: @ekhumoro I know about that situation, and I really hate that behavior, as its behavior is often erratic and annoying. About the first point, yes, that's true, but then again, checking against a *translation* of a button text in order to set another name (especially considering the possible purpose of the button and the reason for the renaming) is certainly not an optimal nor advisable choice.

Comment: @musicamante Why not optimal or advisable? Whether translated or not, the strings will be static, so the comparison will work the same. It would be a bug if it didn't. If it weren't for the dubious behaviour of some styles, there would be no reason to think twice about it.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm not saying it's wrong, but it has more drawbacks than benefits. For instance, it's much prone to undetectable typos: if the check is done in multiple places and the default string is changed (consider that the OP used "start" in the question, and then decides to use "Start" instead), that requires to change it everywhere and risk missing some, with the result of failing both conditions of this answer. Then there's the point of semantics: a button and function like those reflect and react to a logic state, which is better represented in code by a dedicated type ->

Comment: -> (in this case, a bool) which improves both readability and debugging. Even using custom enums would be better anyway, as in case of typos they would be catched at some point. In fact, the very existence of that annoying "bug" (which doesn't directly affect execution) is yet another reason for which all this should be generally avoided for this kind of situations. While in this case we're (theoretically) just altering the string (which would then make sense), the button name and text choice clearly are representations of a *state*, so the string comparison is far less indicated for this.